# couchdb query map view and not reduce view

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

How do I query just the map of a view with both a map and reduce using evently?

**Here is what I have so far in data.js:**

```
function(data) {
  var numRows = data.rows.map(function(r) {
    return r
  }); //this is returning an object that is the result of the reduce function
      // but I want the total_rows of the map function 

  var sum = data.rows.reduce(function(r) {
    return r.value
  }); //this returns the sum of all row values
  var avg = sum.value / numRows
  $.log(avg);
  $.log(numRows);
  return {'total': numRows, 'average': avg}
};
```

I want this to return the total number of rows from the query and the average of their values.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have couchapp at hand right now to test, but I think you are confusing [JavaScript map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with CouchDB view map function. Doing `data.rows.map()` you are calling the `Array.map` function on the `data.rows` array. What you are looking for should be in `data.total_rows`.

Read [this tutorial](http://couchapp.org/page/evently-do-it-yourself-ii-state) for more information.

**UPDATE:** the number of rows is data.rows.length.